# why i cant enter second main file in python(error: file not found error)

Tags: python, operating-system

the problem is that cant enter second main file.

can anyone explain to me why its behaving this way and possibly suggest how i could fix it?

thank you.

here is code :

```
for i in os.listdir(os.chdir('TXTs')):
if i[0] != '.':
    print(i,'-'*50)
    try:
        for j in os.listdir(os.chdir(i)):
            if j[0] != '.':
                print(j)
    except:
        pass
```

here is output:

```
mgk --------------------------------------------------
mgk-d00
danisma-meclisi-d00
kapali-oturum --------------------------------------------------
cs --------------------------------------------------
tbt --------------------------------------------------
millet-meclisi --------------------------------------------------
kurucu-meclis --------------------------------------------------
```

here is output without try/except:

```
mgk --------------------------------------------------
mgk-d00
danisma-meclisi-d00
kapali-oturum --------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mete/Documents/projects/tbmm/test.py", line 22, in <module>
    for j in os.listdir(os.chdir(i)):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'kapali-oturum'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but you're using `os.chdir()` wrong. That function returns `None`, but you're nonetheless using its return value as an argument to `os.listdir()`. Also, don't use `i` and `j` as variable names for files; it's confusing. Those variable names are usually used for integers, especially for loop indices.

Comment: i was tryng to select txt files in all directory. i was just testing. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs at `for j in os.listdir(os.chdir(i)):` because `os.chdir()` will change your scripts working directory.
During the first loop where `i` is `mgk`, the script will change it's working directory to `TXTs/mgk` rather than staying at `TXTs`.
To fix this, you either want to change back to `TXTs` directory after the second loop ends.

```
for i in os.listdir(os.chdir('TXTs')):
if i[0] != '.':
    print(i,'-'*50)
    try:
        for j in os.listdir(os.chdir(i)):
            if j[0] != '.':
                print(j)
        os.chdir("..")  # Return to parent directory which is TXTs
    except:
        pass
```

Or list sub directories without changing your current working directory

```
for i in os.listdir(os.chdir('TXTs')):
if i[0] != '.':
    print(i,'-'*50)
    try:
        for j in os.listdir(i):  # Don't change the directory at all
            if j[0] != '.':
                print(j)
    except:
        pass
```

[More about os.listdir() here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)
[More about os.chdir() here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir)